# How to use tf.argmax

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I want to test the function of tf.argmax(),but when I run the code , I encountered an error. Here is my code

```
import tensorflow as tf
 
a=tf.argmax([1,0,0],1)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(a))
```

My environment is python3 + tf1.3.

What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1):

In tensorflow argmax() and argmin() functions are used to find the largest and the smallest value index in a vector. The problem with your code is that you specified the axis argument as "1" which means that you want to search in two dimension array.Check this link:https://www.dotnetperls.com/arg-max-tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf

a=tf.argmax([1,0,0],0)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(a))
```